# Is it possible to get the url of an iframe when the src is https and the parent is http?

Tags: javascript, iframe, https

I get an error on String(u).indexOf() saying access denied http to https...  so I'm thinking this doesn't work. But maybe i'm missing something.

**This is on the same domain, just a different protocol.**

```
  function process_form(f){


    var l = $("iframe#loginFrame");    
    if(l.length==0){      
      f.attr("target","loginFrame");      
      $('<iframe src="/player.htm?ajax=1"'+(!_DBG?' class="hide"':'')+' id="loginFrame" name="loginFrame"></iframe>').prependTo('body');      
      $("iframe#loginFrame").load(function() {
        var u = this.contentWindow.location;


        if(String(u).indexOf("confirm")>=0){ 
          change_form(1);
        }else if(u!=this.src){
          change_form(0);
        }
        log(u);
        log(this.src);

      });



    }else{
      warn("Frame already exists!"); 
    }

    change_form(-1);
    setTimeout(function(){ f.submit();},500);
    log(f);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your accessing a different domain, you will really have that `access denied` error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access any information in https from http!